# Group by and counting the number of unique values across multiple columns (mysql)

Tags: mysql

```
ID ArrivalPort DeparturePort
1  A           B
1  A           C
2  A           B
2  C           D
```

How do I do a unique/distinct count of both the `ArrivalPort` and `DeparturePort` by `ID`?

```
Out
ID   Count
1    3
2    4
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a union in a derived tabled then count:

```
select ID, count(distinct Port) as Count from
(select id, ArrivalPort as Port from table_name
union all select id, DeparturePort from table_name) t
group by id;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fe2c718036521837c4bde14adb6b18a1)